# Creating user interface for ZORK style game in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, interactive, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to use MATLAB to create a stand-alone application for an interactive fiction game (where the player is presented with a text prompt and responds by entering text, e.g. "You are being choked by a creepy squid. >> " "Stab squid" "The squid dies, leaving behind an inky pile of gold. >>" etc.).

When I compile the game and install it, everything works smoothly, but there's nowhere for the game's prompts to appear, and nowhere for the user to type in responses.

Who has a good solution for this? Do I use a GUI with text boxes, or is there a way just to have a text scroll with user inputs like [this](http://iplayif.com/?story=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifarchive.org%2Fif-archive%2Fgames%2Fzcode%2Fzdungeon.z5)? The latter would be preferable.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't using the Matlab console for both input actions and displaying events?

Comment: I can do that within MATLAB. However, I want to write my function to a standalone application that people can play without having MATLAB installed on their computer. Is there a way to include the MATLAB console in a standalone application?

Comment: Well, when you execute a compiled file the output generated by Matlab goes to your system console. You can request user input from that console using `input`  https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html